# Create table similar to histogram in r

Tags: r, dataframe

The histogram function in ggplot2 simplifies a fairly complex task. Is there a function or package that does the same but creates a table or data frame?

```
# Sample data
list <-c ("Goal","Shot on goal","Blocked","Miss")
type <- sample(list, 100, replace=TRUE)
xG <- runif(100)
df <- tibble(Type = type, xG = xG)

# Plot
p <- df %>% ggplot(.,aes(x = xG, fill=Type)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.3)
p
```

So instead of plotting the data it would create a data frame with the columns and rows (in bins) as such:

Rows: .00-.25 .26-.50 .51-.75 .76-1.00

Columns: Goal, Shot on goal, Blocked, Miss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` to divide data into different `bins` and then `count`.

```
df %>%
  dplyr::count(Type, bins = cut(xG, seq(0, 1, 0.25))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = n)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  bins       Blocked  Goal  Miss `Shot on goal`
  <fct>        <int> <int> <int>          <int>
1 (0,0.25]         6     7     6             10
2 (0.25,0.5]       7    NA    10              6
3 (0.5,0.75]       4    12     7              3
4 (0.75,1]         4     4     6              8
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!